# Update column value from another columns based on multiple conditions in spark structured streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, multiple-conditions

I want to update the value in one column using another two columns based on multiple conditions. For eg - the stream is like :

```
    +---+---+----+---+
    | A | B | C  | D |
    +---+---+----+---+
    | a | T | 10 | 0 |
    | a | T | 100| 0 |
    | a | L | 0  | 0 |
    | a | L | 1  | 0 |
    +---+---+----+---+
```

What I have is multiple conditions like -

> (B = "T" && C > 20 ) OR (B = "L" && C = 0)

The values `"T"`, `20`, `"L"` and `0` are dynamic. `AND/OR` operators are also supplied at run-time. I want to make `D = 1` whenever the condition holds true else it should remain `D = 0`. The number of conditions are also dynamic.

I tried using it with the `UPDATE` command in `spark-sql` i.e. `UPDATE df SET D = '1' WHERE CONDITIONS`. But it says that update is not yet supported. The resulting dataframe should be -

```
+---+---+----+---+
| A | B | C  | D |
+---+---+----+---+
| a | T | 10 | 0 |
| a | T | 100| 1 |
| a | L | 0  | 1 |
| a | L | 1  | 0 |
+---+---+----+---+
```

Is there any way I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you are using Python. Will also post same for Scala as well! Use `udf`

`PYTHON`

```
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  T| 10|  0|
|  a|  T|100|  0|
|  a|  L|  0|  0|
|  a|  L|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+

>>> def get_column(B, C):
...     return int((B == "T" and C > 20) or (B == "L" and C == 0))
...
>>> fun = udf(get_column)
>>> res = df.withColumn("D", fun(df['B'], df['C']))>>> res.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  T| 10|  0|
|  a|  T|100|  1|
|  a|  L|  0|  1|
|  a|  L|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

`SCALA`

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  T| 10|  0|
|  a|  T|100|  0|
|  a|  L|  0|  0|
|  a|  L|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+


scala> def get_column(B : String, C : Int) : Int = {     
     |     if((B == "T" && C > 20) || (B == "L" && C == 0))
     |         1     
     |     else
     |         0
     | }
get_column: (B: String, C: Int)Int

scala> val fun = udf(get_column _)
fun: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,IntegerType,Some(List(StringType, IntegerType)
))

scala> val res = df.withColumn("D", fun(df("B"), df("C")))
res: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [A: string, B: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> res.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  T| 10|  0|
|  a|  T|100|  1|
|  a|  L|  0|  1|
|  a|  L|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

You can also use `case` `when` and `otherwise` like this:

`PYTHON`

```
>>> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  T| 10|  0|
|  a|  T|100|  0|
|  a|  L|  0|  0|
|  a|  L|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+

>>> new_column = when(
        (col("B") == "T") & (col("C") > 20), 1
    ).when((col("B") == "L") & (col("C") == 0), 1).otherwise(0)

>>> res = df.withColumn("D", new_column)
>>> res.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  T| 10|  0|
|  a|  T|100|  1|
|  a|  L|  0|  1|
|  a|  L|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```

`SCALA`

```
scala> df.show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  T| 10|  0|
|  a|  T|100|  0|
|  a|  L|  0|  0|
|  a|  L|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+

scala> val new_column = when(
     |     col("B") === "T" && col("C") > 20, 1
     | ).when(col("B") === "L" && col("C") === 0, 1 ).otherwise(0)

new_column: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = CASE WHEN ((B = T) AND (C > 20)) THEN 1 WHEN ((B = L) AND (C = 0)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

scala> df.withColumn("D", new_column).show()
+---+---+---+---+
|  A|  B|  C|  D|
+---+---+---+---+
|  a|  T| 10|  0|
|  a|  T|100|  1|
|  a|  L|  0|  1|
|  a|  L|  1|  0|
+---+---+---+---+
```